# How to make the results of complex queries easily accessible?

Tags: postgresql

I want to run queries that compute some KPIs on time series data for a specific time period, e.g. the KPI for Mai, June, July, etc.

The results should somehow be "stored" so that they can be accessed using a simple SQL statement such as `SELECT * FROM kpi_for_june` or something equally simple.

I was thinking about:

1. Storing the data physically in new tables, however, this would probably need a more complex query with a WHERE clause. Furthermore, it would make the database schema more complex which I would like to avoid.
2. Using views with a separate view for each month, leading to a lot of views since there are multiple KPIs to be stored.
3. Using functions (I have no experience with that)

Some of the queries take 1-2 hours to complete and the results range from a couple of rows to up to 10.000 rows.
The Postgres version is 13.8.

Are there best practices or recommendations?

Comment: Once calculated, this derived data won't change?

Comment: No, it will not change

Answer (score 0):

First, do not have a new object for each month. Make the month a column and store all the values in a single object. Queries then are something like `SELECT * FROM kpi WHERE month_name = 'June'`. Life will be so much easier in the long term.

If the calculation has many steps spread over many statements my preference is for using intermediate working tables and one final kpi table to hold the final output. This make incremental debugging and restart after failure simpler. However it may be slower because of the extra writes.

For logically simple calculations which just take a long time to churn through the data a [materialised view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html) will be your friend. The downside is that historical kpi rows will be lost if that month's data no longer in the source tables.